# Need help with this one piece! (Floral ornment)

Tags: modeling

So I need to do this handle in 3D. I already made that bubble top part, but I need that "Flower pattern", and I only have this reference image. How would I approach and make this ? Because modeling it with hand seems impossible..

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to do it manually, what other idea did you have?

Comment: Curves are probably the most appropriate solution for this. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJsxKWxAhMk) explains how to create floral ornaments.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it:

- **Manually**. It will garantee that you're very close to the real object and you'll be able to make some close-up shots. Here is just a try with a small detail, you'll need to do if with whole shape of course:

[image]

[image]

- With a **Project From View** texture: Draw the contours of the whole shape, extrude up, bevel, shade smooth, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, unwrap from the top orthogonal view with the *Project from View* option, give it a material with the original photo as *Image Texture*, you can even add a bit of bump:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- You can even cut with the knife or inset to extrude up or down some parts:

[image]

- With **curves**: Draw some curves that roughly follow the ornments, bevel them, use the *Profile* tool, scale the vertices with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> if you want more thickness, and when you're glad, convert to mesh:

[image]